# ${{a}_{n+1}}=\frac{{{a}_{n}}+{{a}_{n+2}}}{2}$ for all $n \ge 1$. Then$\{{{a}_{n}}\}$is unbounded.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, upper-lower-bounds, arithmetic-progressions

Let $\{{{a}_{n}}\}$ be a non-constant sequence in $\mathbb R $ such that ${{a}_{n+1}}=\frac{{{a}_{n}}+{{a}_{n+2}}}{2}$ for all $n \ge 1$. Then $\{{{a}_{n}}\}$ is unbounded.

> > Geometrically I plotted the sequences and understand inter distance between any two consecutive terms is fixed and $a_2-a_1$. So it is either increasing or decreasing. But how to prove it is unbounded.

Comment: WLOG assume increasing. Assume that you have an upper bound M. See if you can find some `n` for which a_n is more than M.

Comment: @SarthakRout You can't just assume it's increasing without loss of generality, except if you prove it is monotonous first.

Comment: @5xum You are right. Though, I don't think that is where the OP is stuck.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

The distance between $a_n-a_1$ is a multiple of $a_2-a_1$. Now tend $n$ to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that
$$a_{n+2} = 2a_{n+1} -  a_n \iff a_{n+2} - a_{n+1} = a_{n+1}-a_n.$$
Define the sequence $(s_n)$ by $s_n = a_{n+1} - a_n$. Then, $(s_n)$ is a constant sequence, with $s_1 = a_2 - a_1 =: b$. Now,
$$ nb = \sum_{k = 1}^n s_k = a_{n+1} - a_1.$$
Therefore, $(a_n)$ is unbounded iff $a_1\neq a_2$.